# Store Dropdown list old values and re populate them

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I store the old value of the drop down list?

Comment: And with which part of your code you have some troubles? Right now you haven't actually asked a question. You have only posted your customer/manager/teacher specifications about some functionality that you need to implement. But StackOverflow is not a rent-a-coder site.

Comment: I agree with you..Plz see the edit.

Comment: whats stopping you from chucking the selected value in a hidden field/variable, and then reading it again on reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please tell me how can i store the old value of the drop down list.

One possibility is to store them in a temporary javascript array using the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function:

```
var oldValues = ​$('#myselect option')​.map(function() {
    return { value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text() };
});
```

or completely clone the dropdownlist using the [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method:

```
var dropdown = $('#myselect').clone(true);
```

and later restore it back.